# Extracting the string with "/"

Tags: c

I could extract the string fs and lost+found using strtok with the delimiter as "/". But I couldn't concatenate the tokenised string to /fs/lost+found/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char* path_val(char* paths){
        char* temp =  strtok(paths,"/");
        char* path = temp;
        char* begin = path;
        printf("\n %s \n",temp);
        /* Concatenating with /fs */
        strcat(path,"/");
        strcat(path,temp);
        while(temp != NULL){
                if(strcmp(temp,"lost+found") == 0){
                         printf("\n Found! \n");
                         /* Concatenating with / and lost+found */
                         strcat(path,"/");
                         strcat(path,temp);
                         printf("\n path : %s \n",begin);
                         return temp;
                }
                temp = strtok(NULL,"/");
        }
}
int main(){
        char path[] = "/fs/lost+found/df/er/te";
        char *name = path_val(path);
        printf("\n name : %s \n",name);
        return 0;
}
```

I wanted to extract /fs/lost+found. Tried the above program but couldnt get the correct string.

Comment: It looks like you asked the same question again.   Please do not duplicate questions.

Comment: You may wanna look at the man page of strtok(). There is an example much like your. 'http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok'

Comment: Well it is the same general problem, and the same poster, but **not** the same problem. First question problem **was** about correct `strtok` usage, this one is about correct `strcat` usage ! For angus : the error is that you should never modify the return value of strtok, but the question was closed before I could answer.

Comment: Yeah. But I'm trying to concatenate and is not getting the string.

Comment: This is not the same question.

Comment: Since `char* path = temp;` you have the same value for both parameters to `strcat(path,temp);` and get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code :

- you pass a buffer to `strtok` multiple times to get different tokens and simultaneously modify it with `strcat`. That's bad. What is even worse is that what you cat to be buffer `path` is already part of same buffer. As harper said it leads to undefined behavior
- you do not return the correct value : you only return last token instead of returning the whole prefix

You could try something like :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char* path_val(char* paths){
        char* path = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(paths));
        char* temp =  strtok(paths,"/");
        char* begin = path;
        printf("\n %s \n",temp);
        while(temp != NULL){
                strcat(path,"/");
                strcat(path,temp);
                if(strcmp(temp,"lost+found") == 0){
                         printf("\n Found! \n");
                         printf("\n path : %s \n",begin);
                         return path;
                }
                temp = strtok(NULL,"/");
        }
}
int main(){
        char path[] = "/fs/lost+found/df/er/te";
        char *name = path_val(path);
        printf("\n name : %s \n",name);
        free(name);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to obtaining your wanted path is to remove one end path component at a time and then compare the new path with the wanted path. The simple way to implement this logic is through a function that will take a copy of the original path, remove the last component, and compare against the wanted path. The copy preserves the original path string for use, as `strtok` or `setting '/' to '\0'` modify the original. A simple while loop in main can just as easily be placed in the `path_trim` function as well. (although preventing memory leaks is easier in main()) Here is a simple implementation. It works both with, or without, the trailing slash on the end of the path:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/** Trims last path component from full path string.
*  Returns everything prior to last '/' as path.
*/
char *path_trim (char *path) 
{
    size_t len = strlen (path);     /* get length of original path      */
    char *p = path + (len - 2);     /* set pointer to next to last char */
                                    /* (prevents break on trailing '/') */
    while (p-- >= path)             /* work backwards through path      */
        if (*p == '/') {            /* if *p == '/', set value = null   */
            *p = 0;
            break;                  /* break */
        }

    return (p > path) ? p : path;   /* if no '/' return original path   */
}

int main () {

    char path[] = "/fs/lost+found/df/er/te";
    char *name = strdup (path);         /* duplicate path to modify      */

    printf ("\n path : %s\n", path);    /* output original path          */

    while (strcmp (name, "/fs/lost+found") != 0) /* while name not path  */
    {
        path_trim (name);           /* trim one path component from end  */
        if (strlen (name) < 1)      /* path < 1, not found, break        */
            break;
    }

    printf(" name : %s \n\n",name); /* print final path name found       */
    if (name) free (name);          /* free memory allocate to name      */

    return 0;
}
```

**Build:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/pval pathval.c
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./bin/pval

 path : /fs/lost+found/df/er/te
 name : /fs/lost+found
```

**Valgrind Summary:**

```
==16802== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16802==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16802==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==16802==
==16802== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16802==
==16802== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```